# App Getting Crash After Uploading the Image to Server IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Hi I'm uploading the image to my server form my device but its getting crash after its get uploaded to server. In code i have given the provision like after uploading the image it has to go back to the main view after adding this code its keep getting crash.

Upload Code..

```
    NSString *urlString = @"http://indianpoliticalleadersmap.com/IOS/upload/photos/upload.php";

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageview.image,90);
    long imageSize = imageData.length;
    NSLog(@"SIZE OF IMAGE: %.2f Mb", (float)imageSize/1024/1024);
 if (imageSize > 4.194e+6) {

     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"your image exceeds more then 4mb pls upload below 4mb image" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     [alert show];
     [alert release];
    }
   else
  {
       NSString *urlString = @"url";

       NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init]autorelease];
       [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] ;
       [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

       NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
       NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
       [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

       NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
       [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
       [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
       [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
       [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
       [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
       [request setHTTPBody:body];

       NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
       NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

       NSLog(@"%@data",returnString);
       [self temp];
       [self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0f];
       [self performSelector:@selector(dissMissViewController) withObject:self afterDelay:4.0f];
       alertTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(showAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

     }
   }
```

The app gets crash after the alert message pops up when i click the OK in alert message app gets crash Please tell me how to resolve this one.

```
  -(void)showAlert{

     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Thanks" message:@"For uploading Image" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
     [alert show];
     [alert release];
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your crash log .

Comment: @V-Xtreme its showing as Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1 address0xc00000c)

Comment: @V-Xtreme pls check the code which i have updated now

Comment: May be problem with alertview make delegate to nil in your alertview show method

Comment: @Sunnyshah pls tell me how to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your crash log but if your app crash after alert. then the problem will be delegate.

You should replaces `delegate=nil` instead of `delegate=self`

```
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"your image exceeds more then 4mb pls upload below 4mb image" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
 [alert show];
```

Comment: shan  i already given self in delegate but its still getting crash

Comment: please check my updated code i have given my alert message code

Comment: dont add self make nil then try

Answer (score 0):

Generally  `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is due to improper memory management . I cant figure out exact problem . But I think you should just check that by removing `[alert release]` .

Also try check if you have add UIAlertViewDelegate to .h file .

Comment: after removing the release also its showing the same problem